# Why does generator's .next need a setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, generator, ecmascript-6, yield

I'm experimenting with ES6's generator functions and yield statements, [Example](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%0A%0Afunction%20run%20(generator)%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20itr%20%3D%20generator(resume)%3B%0A%20%20function%20resume(callbackValue)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20itr.next(callbackValue)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20itr.next()%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20*main(resume)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20result1%20%3D%20yield%20add(1%2C%20resume)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20data1%20%3D%20result1%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22add%201%20%3D%20%22%2C%20data1)%0A%20%20%20%20var%20data2%20%3D%20yield%20add(1%2C%20resume)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22add%201%20%3D%20%22%2C%20data2)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20var%20data3%20%3D%20yield%20add(data1%2C%20resume)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22add%20data1%20%3D%22%2C%20data3)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22total%20is%20%22%2C%20data1%2Bdata2%2Bdata3)%3B%0A%7D%0Afunction%20add%20(num%2C%20resume)%20%7B%0A%09setTimeout(function%20()%20%7B%0A%09%20%20resume(num%20%2B%201)%3B%0A%09%7D%2C0)%3B%0A%7D%20%0Arun(main)%3B).

```
function run(generator) {
  var itr = generator(resume);

  function resume(callbackValue) {
    itr.next(callbackValue);
  }
  itr.next();
}

function* main(resume) {
  var result1 = yield add(1, resume);
  var data1 = result1;
  console.log("add 1 = ", data1)
  var data2 = yield add(1, resume);
  console.log("add 1 = ", data2);
  var data3 = yield add(data1, resume);
  console.log("add data1 =", data3);
  console.log("total is ", data1 + data2 + data3);
}

function add(num, resume) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    resume(num + 1);
  }, 0);
}

run(main);
```

I plan on using yield as flow control for asynchronous REST calls, where the request will call next once it has a response, but for now I'm just using a simple adding function. It works as planned which is exciting but resume will only work with in the setTimeout and I'm not sure why. 
If it just have:

```
function add (num, resume) {
    resume(num + 1);
}
```

the interpreter gives me 'Generator is already running'.

There doesn't need to be an actual wait in the time for the timeout, and I also tried a self invoking function, but that didn't help. Why does `itr.next()` need a timeout?

Comment: Because you're calling `next` inside a `yield` expression - you have to wait for the `yield` to finish.

Comment: Then I'm not sure I understand the order of operations, because all yield is doing really is calling that function, unless assigning the value and calling console.log count as part of it.

Comment: yield runs on an expression, that expression has not evaluated yet, and you're calling .next again

Comment: setTimeout(function, 0) - makes the code inside it run as fast, as other actions that are already in EventLoop finish.

Answer (score 3):

As other commenters said, you're trying to call `resume` while the `yield` expression is still resolving. Asynchronously calling `itr.next` will allow the yield expression to finish, and then immediately call `itr.next` when it's done. To get it to work the way you want, just change `run`:

```
function run(generator) {
  var itr = generator(resume);

  function resume(callbackValue) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      itr.next(callbackValue);
    }, 0);
  }
  itr.next();
}
```

This is a really fun idea, and it could [actually be useful](https://gist.github.com/tablekat/fad9728843ef5b54eb0455f43c546e43).